# Is there a difference between android:layout_centerVertical and android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"?

Tags: android, xml, layout, gravity

I guess the title says it all. What is the difference between the two (if there is one) XML attributes and when would one be better used over the other?

```
...
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
...
```

and

```
...
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, layout_centerVertical is only valid for RelativeLayouts.  Gravity is also valid for linear layouts, so you could tell a LL with horizontal orientation to center objects vertically that otherwise would be top or bottom aligned.